# Using Android Material Design Text in last Line is cutting

Tags: android, material-design

I am using Google Material design specifications in my application resulting in trimming alphabets in last line .

Taking reference from : https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@color/white_color"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_subtask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="56dp"
        android:paddingTop="17dp"
        android:text="Single Line Item "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

note_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:background="@color/note_color"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto regular"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Groups "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" /><android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto regular"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Groups"
        android:textColor="#707066"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try increasing height of linearlayout

Comment: what happens when you give padding to the text view?

Comment: Decrease paddingTop;

Comment: Decreasing padding from top solves my problem .
Thank u all :)